# Loop over arbitrarily nested data in a Jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following list of dicts, where each dict can have a `children` key with a further list of dicts. This can be nested arbitrarily deep. How can I loop over this in Jinja to output nested lists?

```
[{
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Level 1',
    'children': [{
        'id': '11',
        'name': 'Level 1.1'
    }, {
        'id': '12',
        'name': 'Level 1.2'
    }, {
        'id': '13',
        'name': 'Level 1.3',
        'children': [{
             'id': '131',
             'name': 'Level 1.3.1'
         }]
    }]
},
{
    'id': '2',
    'name': 'Level 2',
    'children': [{
        'id': '21',
        'name': 'Level 2.1'
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`recursive`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) option in the `for` loop. Now calling the special `loop` variable will repeat the loop with the nested content.

```
<ul>
    {% for item in data recursive %}
    <li>{{ item.name }}
    {% if item.children %}
        <ul>{{ loop(item.children) }}</ul>
    {% endif %}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```